# "can only concatenate str (not "list") to str" while adding zeros to binary number

Tags: python

I am making on RSA. I need to put zeros on the left side of my really big binary number.
I have this list:

```py
text = ['110000100001101000000011011110000110101000001100100000011000010000010000000001101101', '11101000000111010100001100001000011011000000110111000001100101']
```

And I want to get this

```py
text= ['0000110000100001101000000011011110000110101000001100100000011000010000010000000001101101', '000011101000000111010100001100001000011011000000110111000001100101']
```

In this case there miss 4 zeros on the left side.
I tried this loop:

```py
i = 0;
while i < len(text):
    j = 0
    zeroCount = (10 - (len(text[i]) % 11)) + 1
    while j < zeroCount:
        text[i] = '0' + text[i]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Which doesn't work in my PyQt project. However it works when I have tried it in blank untitled1.py "sketchbook". It's kind of confusing. What am I doing wrong and why it works in my "sketchbook"?

Comment: This code works as-is for me.  The code in your PyQt project must be different.  Can you edit the question to include the full error message, so we can see exactly where the error is?

Comment: I agree with @JohnGordon. With your error, the code implies that it is similar to `text[i] = '0' + text` due to the concentration error.

Comment: Variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. `zeroCount` -> `zero_count`. Why is there a semicolon in the line `i = 0;`? What's a "sketchbook"?

Comment: What error do you get for PyQT?

Comment: List comprehension is half line solution. see my answer

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: cannot reproduce in ipython but see my answer that should work in all environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use list comprehension:**

```
text = ['110000100001101000000011011110000110101000001100100000011000010000010000000001101101', '11101000000111010100001100001000011011000000110111000001100101']

result = ["0"*(10 - (len(i) % 11) + 1) + "{}".format(i) for i in text]
```

It will add 4 zeros in front of each binary string.

```
print(result)
['0000110000100001101000000011011110000110101000001100100000011000010000010000000001101101', '000011101000000111010100001100001000011011000000110111000001100101']
```

Comment: @Axiumin_ OP's desired output adds exactly four zeroes to both strings.

Comment: @JohnGordon: "In this case"

Comment: This is it. Thank you :]. I also had some bugs in my code. That's why my loop didn't work. Also your code is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for i, binary_number in enumerate(text):
    text[i] = ((10 - (len(text[i]) % 11)) + 1) * '0' + text[i]
```

this will add the zeros you want to every binary string in your list.

Comment: too long. List comprehension is half line solution

Comment: It may be too long, but is pretty easy to read, and also a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most straightforward (and up to date) way of doing it.

```py
bin_strs = ['110000100001101000000011011110000110101000001100100000011000010000010000000001101101',
            '11101000000111010100001100001000011011000000110111000001100101']

bin_strs_pad = ['0' * ((10 - (len(curr) % 11)) + 1) + curr for curr in bin_strs]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `format` to get the desired result. Use the format specifier `0xxb`, where xx is the desired number of bits in the output. For example, if you want the numbers to be 16 bits long:

```
>>> t = "11001" # example, non zero-padded binary number
>>>"{0:016b}".format(int(t, 2)) # pad with zeros up to 16 bits
'0000000000011001'
```

Alternatively, with f-strings (Python 3.6+):

```
>>> t = "11001"
>>> f"{int(t,2):016b}"
'0000000000011001'
```

The other answers are fixated on having the shortest list comprehension, and matching OP's modulo 11 approach, but this is the [one obvious way](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) to format a binary number to a desired length.

Comment: why are you adding `00000000000` when OP's desired output adds 4 zero's?

Comment: @Axiumin: This is a general solution, for any number of zeros you want to add. The typical use case for wanting to prepend zeros to a binary number is that without the leading zeros, the length is not a multiple of 8, and you need 16 or 32, or in this case 88 bits.